# MySQL : Use filter query in Where clause

Tags: mysql

I need help to build a SQL query to get the data for projects created in 2020. I have two tables :

Project table :

| ProjectID | ProjectName | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project1 | A |
| 2 | Project2 | A |
| 3 | Project3 | C |
| 4 | Project4 | B |

Table Task :

| ProjectID | TaskID | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TA | 2020-1-1 |
| 1 | 4 | TA | 2019-12-15 |
| 1 | 2 | TB | 2020-5-1 |
| 2 | 3 | TB | 2021-1-1 |
| 1 | 5 | TB | 2020-10-1 |
| 2 | 6 | TA | 2020-3-14 |
| 3 | 7 | TB | 2020-10-1 |

The start date of a project equals the date of the first task (without consideration of type). I need details of the tasks (TB type) of the projects started in or after 2020.

Result :

| ProjectID | TaskID | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | TB | 2020-10-1 |
| 2 | 3 | TB | 2021-1-1 |

I have tried

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  task t 
  LEFT JOIN project p ON p.projectID = t.projectID 
WHERE 
  t.type = 'TB' year(
    min(t.date)
  ) >= '2020'
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: and why do you exclude project 1?

Comment: Because the first task is in 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use HAVING with a subquery and an Group function

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TASKS
>     (`ProjectID` int, `TaskID` int, `Type` varchar(2), `Date` varchar(10))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO TASKS
>     (`ProjectID`, `TaskID`, `Type`, `Date`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 'TA', '2020-1-1'),
>     (1, 4, 'TA', '2019-12-15'),
>     (1, 2, 'TB', '2020-5-1'),
>     (2, 3, 'TB', '2021-1-1'),
>     (1, 5, 'TB', '2020-10-1'),
>     (2, 6, 'TA', '2020-3-14'),
>     (3, 7, 'TB', '2020-10-1')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PROJECTS
>     (`ProjectID` int, `ProjectName` varchar(8), `Type` varchar(1))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO PROJECTS
>     (`ProjectID`, `ProjectName`, `Type`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Project1', 'A'),
>     (2, 'Project2', 'A'),
>     (3, 'Project3', 'C'),
>     (4, 'Project4', 'B')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> t.*
> FROM 
>   TASKS t 
>   LEFT JOIN PROJECTS p ON p.ProjectID = t.ProjectID 
> WHERE 
>   t.Type = 'TB' 
>   HAVING (SELECT MIN(year(t.`Date`)) FROM TASKS t WHERE t.ProjectID = p.ProjectID) >= 2020
> ```
>
> ```
> ProjectID | TaskID | Type | Date     
> --------: | -----: | :--- | :--------
>         2 |      3 | TB   | 2021-1-1 
>         3 |      7 | TB   | 2020-10-1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1de0b1799390444fe35301043719dc7b)*

Answer (score 0):

The min date needs to be grouped. You don't need the project table at all to just get tasks. For projects:

```
SELECT *
FROM Project p
WHERE p.projectID IN (SELECT t.projectID FROM task t WHERE t.type = 'TB' AND year(min(t.date)) >= '2020' GROUP BY t.projectID)
```

And for tasks:

```
SELECT *
FROM task p
WHERE p.projectID IN (SELECT t.projectID FROM task t WHERE t.type = 'TB' AND year(min(t.date)) >= '2020' GROUP BY t.projectID)
```

Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: your code will not run because of the  where clause

Comment: Do you want just project table? Or tasks too in the result?

Comment: iyou need an `AND` between type and date, but i don't understand the question, because the wanted result has not the projectid 1 in it

Comment: The project 1 is not included because it has started in 2019 (First task 2019-12-15)

Comment: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: I just fixed with parentheses at the end